# Raspberry Pi 4B is not rebooting from SSH

Tags: ssh, power, raspbian-buster

I have a recently flashed SD card in my Raspberry Pi, I've just been through some setup and have found some errors with my SD card being in Read Only, I tried to reboot from SSH except the raspberry pi does absolutely nothing and keeps running (sudo reboot)

Comment: re-flash and try again

Comment: @JaromandaX thx worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was the SD card, I had to use a new one since some of its sectors were broken

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question :-) Please don't forget to accept this answer with a click on the tick on its left side after two days.